# React search filter using select option and useRef

Tags: reactjs, search, use-ref

I am using useRef to search for specific flights using a flight booking form having input fields and select with options field. The search works with input fields by adding ref={} property to it. However, I don't know how to apply the same method with select fields. Does anyone have a clue about how it's done?

Here's the full code for the Search component below:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, useRef } from "react";
import {Container} from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {faPlane} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

// import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Search = ({ onFlightsChange }) => {
  const departureCity = useRef("");
  const destinationCity = useRef("");
  const departureDate = useRef("");
  const arrivalDate = useRef("");
  const cabinClass = useRef("");
  const numOfPassengers = useRef("");

  const [flights, setFlights] = useState([]);

  function handleClick() {
    console.log("Button clicked");
    var body = {};

    if (departureCity.current.value !== "") {
      body["from"] = departureCity.current.value;
    }

    if (destinationCity.current.value !== "") {
      body["to"] = destinationCity.current.value;
    }

    if (departureDate.current.value !== "") {
      body["departureDate"] = departureDate.current.value;
    }

    if (arrivalDate.current.value !== "") {
      body["arrivalDate"] = arrivalDate.current.value;
    }

    if (cabinClass.current.value !== "") {
      body["eSeatsAvailable"] = cabinClass.current.value;
    }

    if (numOfPassengers.current.value !== "") {
      body["numberOfPassengers"] = numOfPassengers.current.value;
    }
    axios
      .post("/flights/find", body)

      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setFlights(res.data);
        onFlightsChange(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Container>
    <div id="search-form-card" class="card shadow mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <div id="search-form-card-body" className="card-body">
            <p id="search-form-title" class="card-title text-center shadow mb-5 rounded">Find your flight&nbsp;< FontAwesomeIcon icon = {faPlane} color="blue" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select">
                    <option id="departure-city" value="" disabled="" selected="">Departure city</option>
                    <option value="1">Cairo</option>
                    <option value="2">Berlin</option>
                    <option value="3">Paris</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select">
                    <option id="destination-city" value="" disabled="" selected="">Departure city</option>
                    <option value="1">Cairo</option>
                    <option value="2">Berlin</option>
                    <option value="3">Paris</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input 
                placeholder="Departure date" 
                type="text" id="date-picker-example" 
                class="form-control datepicker mb-4" 
                ref={departureDate}
                />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input 
                placeholder="Arrival date" 
                type="text" 
                id="date-picker-example" 
                class="form-control datepicker mb-4" 
                ref={arrivalDate}
                />
                </div>
            </div>    
            <div class="row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select">
                            <option id="departure-time" value="" disabled="" selected="">Departure time</option>
                            <option value="1">6:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="2">3:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="3">6:00 PM</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-6"><select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select">
                            <option 
                            id="departure-time" 
                            value="" disabled="" 
                            selected="">Arrival time
                            
                            </option>
                            <option value="1">6:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="2">3:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="3">6:00 PM</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select">
                            <option id="children" value="" disabled="" selected="">Children</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select">
                            <option id="children" value="" disabled="" selected="">Adults</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>   
                <button className="btn btn-primary float-right mt-5" onClick= 
                {handleClick}>Search</button>
                </div>
            </div><br/>
            
   </Container>

    </Fragment>
  );
};

export { Search };
```

(Modified section):

```
  function handleClick() {
    console.log("Button clicked");
    var body = {};
    let value = null;
    
    if (departureCity.current.value !== "") {
      // body["from"] = departureCity.current.value;
      value = departureCity.current.value;
      
    }
```

```
                <select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select" ref={departureCity}>
                    <option id="departure-city" value="" disabled="" selected="">Departure city</option>
                    <option value="1">Cairo</option>
                    <option value="2">Berlin</option>
                    <option value="3">Paris</option>

                </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's them same as `input`, there is no difference, you can do it like this:

```
const selectRef= useRef("");
...
<select name="myName" id="myId" ref={selectRef}>
  <option valie="myValue">my text</option>
  ...
</select>
```

to read the value related to select, you can do it like what you did with input's ref.

```
const value = selectRef.current.value;
```

BTW there are many duplicated `id` in your code, don't do that, element's id must be unique.

Comment: Thank you for your response.However, I tried your approach and it didn't work. Can you explain in more details in case I didn't get you right? @Saeed Shamloo

Comment: what is your problem? reading value of `select` ?

Comment: I think it is. You can check the modified code. @saeed

Comment: what does this option `<option id="departure-city" value="" disabled="" selected="">Departure city</option>` do? I think you should remove it

Comment: It's the default value of the select box. Besides, I removed it and it didn't make any difference. Maybe the problem is that he doesn't read the const named value I initialized in the handleClick() method. Shouldn't this "value" refer to the one in the options tag ?@saeed

Comment: would you like to try it on online editor? take a look at here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j87q7p

Comment: `class` is wrong, you should use `className`, you shouldn't use `disabled=""`,  just use `disabled` or `disabled={true}`, also don't use selected attribute on option, it's better to use value on `select` tag, I implemented an example to read value of `select` by ref at the link in previous comment, please check it out.

Comment: It worked, my mistake was that I gave numbers(1,2 & 3 in my case) to value attributes and not the the names of the cities. Thank you for your effort, I really appreciate it! @saeed